# Is there any "publicPath" option or similar in Webpack DllPlugin?

Tags: javascript, webpack, react-boilerplate, dllplugin

I'm using [mxstbr/react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate) that uses the great [DllPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#dllplugin), but as the application is served by nginx under `/admin`, it fails with an 404 when trying to get the `reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js` file from the root url (it hits `http://localhost/reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js` instead of `http://localhost/admin/reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js`).

Is there any similar concept to Webpack's [publicPath](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/Configuration#outputpublicpath) option on DllPlugin or any way of telling DllPlugin that is being used under a path prefix?

Answer (score 0):

I did it adding the prefix [where the dll scripts are appended to the body](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/master/internals/webpack/webpack.dev.babel.js#L134):

`` dllNames.forEach((dllName) => body.append(`<script data-dll='true' src='/${dllName}.dll.js'></script>`)); ``

to

`` dllNames.forEach((dllName) => body.append(`<script data-dll='true' src='/${somePrefix}${dllName}.dll.js'></script>`)); ``

Also, depending on how are you proxying the requests, you should ensure the dev server handles the filename correctly. So if you are also passing the prefix to the dev server, you should remove it from the request path [here](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/master/server/middlewares/frontendMiddleware.js#L29).

Answer (score 0):

For webpack.dev.babel.js format, click [here](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/internals/webpack/webpack.dev.babel.js#L134)

I was struggling with the same but tried the following :

1) Go to you webpack.dev.babel.js

2) Go to the line where you've added this :

dllNames.forEach((dllName) => body.append(`<script data-dll='true' src='/${dllName}.dll.js'></script>`));

3) Remove 'backslash'(/) as node_modules files once installed are publicly available.  So, after removing, it will be :

dllNames.forEach((dllName) => body.append(`<script data-dll='true' src='${dllName}.dll.js'></script>`));

4) run npm run build:dll

5) npm start

I hope, it helps.